# Superfish menu dropdown Effects

Tags: jquery, html, css, superfish

I'm using `superfish` menu my question is How many different types of menu drop-down default animations in `superfish` menu.

I search but getting two animations `fade` and `slide-down`.
Is there any other default animations in `superfish`?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can use any available jQuery animation in your Superfish menu.
Just make sure you reverse your animations.

Must look like this in your options: (just an example)

```
.superfish({
...
            animation:     {opacity:'show', marginTop:'+=15px'}, 
            animationOut:  {opacity: 'hide', marginTop:'-=15px'},
...
})
```

With some animations it is essential to use *animationOut* to set the animated submenu back into its original position.

Find all available jQuery animation here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Answer (score -1):

I think fade and slide-down availble for the example -https://superfish.joelbirch.co/examples/

you'r like want any other animation?

Comment: yeah I want to  add other animations.